# Instagram basic display API - Getting Invalid platform app Error

Tags: postman, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am getting Invalid platform app error while hitting oauth/access_token API on postman.

Note - for app_id i am using Instagram App Id.

Any solution for this?

```
{
    "error_type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message": "Invalid platform app"
}
```

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?app_id=54219xxxxx359344&app_secret=190fac2eaacxxxxxxxxxd83e1cc0c382ec7&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fankush2016.github.io%2F&code=AQBSckcUcZ6edpLQlnt2NBCFgfhyJYfEBNW_cFlseJ0R7P2fisA3OWAMU8-BJXbFh0RrKdX0Z7ccrpK7rbZOyQID8epfqcpIGGbUn4oAcdC-sCBYEn2nvuPpjlXoSg5Quv-lq1uiucbqIGKoxH0mDkKDp_QKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxelPn1FoVJqSWqaKbVDtt9rdDlP4n0-aRg__exYWGJ8vqKnp_8dGNxg

Comment: Did you ever figure this out??? I am having the same problem.

Comment: did you add yourself as a tester?

Comment: Same here. I noticed that whatever parameters you put on [https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token/] , **it will throw an error!** Maybe a bad endpoint? 
In any case, I have followed everything step by step mentioned on [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started] and all worked perfectly fine until **Step 5: Exchange the Code for a Token** where I then use postman to call [https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token/] with parameters **client_id, client_secret, grant_type, redirect_uri and code (retrieved after successful authorization)**. but fails

Comment: For what it's worth, there is very fresh and recently attended bug ticket on fb dev (actually it is re-opened). there's even screenshot of the failed postman attempt.
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/647348279410026/

Comment: @MontyTheMack  suggested something. I tried using form-encoded via Postman call and it perfectly worked fine.
Read more here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58488911/authenticate-the-test-user-error-type-oauthexception-code-400-error]

Comment: Thank you @DingDong that works!! I wish they specified that in the documentation. I lost two days on this smh.

Comment: Man, same here! Was two days lost and extremely upset about the docs leaving out this crucial detail! Even that fb guy who is on bug fix [https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/647348279410026/] was of no help. @MontyTheMack

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code format you may wish to use following configuration for your request:

```
baseURL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token"

append = "client_id=\(API.INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID)&client_secret=\(API.INSTAGRAM_CLIENTSERCRET)&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=\(API.INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI)&code=\(code)"

request.httpMethod = "Post"
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type");
```